# PhantomJS does not click button

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to login to Youtube to monetize my videos, but it won't login in. I have checked the element exists when it's reached the code to click the button which it does exist but doesn't seem to click it:

My code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U");

// Fill in the email field
Thread.Sleep(1000);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierId")).SendKeys(Email);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierNext")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// Fill out the password field
driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys(Password);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"passwordNext\"]")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(10000);

//Select the channel if we have more than 1
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[.='" + Name + "']")).Click();

// Select all videos
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"non-appbar-vm-video-actions-bar\"]/div/span[2]/input")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// Click the More button                               
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"non-appbar-vm-video-actions-bar\"]/div/div[1]/button")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// Click Monotime link
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'aria-menu-id')]/descendant::button/span[text()='Monetise']")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// Monetize the video
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"body-container\"]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(20000);

//Close browser
driver.Dispose();
driver.Quit();
driver.Close();
```

Error I am getting:

[image]

The code above works if I use FirefoxDriver, but it doesn't work using PhantomJS.

How can I make it click Google's Next button?

The html of the button:

```
<div role="button" id="identifierNext" class="O0WRkf zZhnYe e3Duub C0oVfc Zp5qWd Hj2jlf qs41qe M9Bg4d" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;" jsshadow="" jsname="tJiF1e" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
    <div class="Vwe4Vb MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd" style="top: 18px; left: 44px; width: 88px; height: 88px;"></div>
    <div class="ZFr60d CeoRYc"></div>
    <content class="CwaK9"><span class="RveJvd snByac">Next</span></content>
</div>
```

I have also tried, with no luck:

```
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, ts);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U");

            // Fill in the email field
            IWebElement web = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("identifierId")));
            web.SendKeys(Email);

            IWebElement nxt = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"identifierNext\"]/content/span")));
            nxt.Click();

            driver.TakeScreenshot().SaveAsFile("screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);

            // Fill out the password field
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("password"))).SendKeys(Password);
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"passwordNext\"]"))).Click();
            driver.TakeScreenshot().SaveAsFile("screenshot2.png", ImageFormat.Png);

            //Select the channel if we have more than 1
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[.='" + Name + "']"))).Click();

            // Select all videos
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"non-appbar-vm-video-actions-bar\"]/div/span[2]/input"))).Click();

            // Click the More button                               
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"non-appbar-vm-video-actions-bar\"]/div/div[1]/button"))).Click();

            // Click Monotime link
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'aria-menu-id')]/descendant::button/span[text()='Monetise']"))).Click();

            // Monetize the video
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"body-container\"]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]"))).Click();

            //Close browser
            driver.Dispose();
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HTML you've provided, I would try clicking on the `<span>` instead:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"identifierNext\"]/content/span")).Click();
```

---

Aside: You may be seeing the effects of the [new Google sign-in page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7338427).

Comment: Tried still the same. I also download the source code via the selnium and that's the html for the button I got.. It's odd, because it works with the FF driver just not the Phantomjs driver :/ I have also tried wait like my new OP update

Comment: Are you being redirected to the old or the new Google sign-in page? I navigated to `"https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U"` via Selenium, and I'm reaching the old sign-in page.

Comment: I screenshotted the page: http://i.imgur.com/swqBK1k.png 

Also I downloaded the selenium page source and it seems to be the news page... How can I get to Google's old page to see if that's the reason why?

Comment: If you disable JavaScript, you'll get redirected to the old sign-in page.

Comment: My selenium is using the new version of Googlemail

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I figured out that if you change the user-agent value for something else like the user agent of a Chrome Browser, you will be able to click on the button "Next" of the Google login experience using the PhantomJS Web Driver.

```
phantomJsOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
     Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36");
```

It seems that the JavaScript could be rendered differently based on the user-agent of the browser.